# Using axios to display an array in a Database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I'm having trouble using axios(my code will follow) but when i use {{response.data}} the site breaks and gives me a blank page as soon as i remove it, it works alright. I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm quite new to using vue, vuetify and axios.

I've got a local server running for the database and the get request link works. it displays 3 columns of strings and 1 array and I'm looking to get the data from the array.

```
<template>
<v-app id="inspire"
     style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
<!-- to be deleted-->
<v-app-bar-nav-icon style="padding-left: 80px">
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">Login</router-link>
      <br>
      <vbtn>Logout</vbtn>
    </nav>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</v-app-bar-nav-icon>
<!--end-->
<!-- profiles to login to-->
<v-main style="padding: 10rem">
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
          v-for="n in 10"
          :key="n"
          cols="5"
          style="background-color: #e4e4e4;">
        <v-card height="200" style="background-color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center">{{n}}</v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-main>
<!-- profiles to login to end-->
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld' ,
  mounted () {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8081/contractor?user_id=c65722")
    .then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
  },
  data: () => ({
    ecosystem: [],
    importantLinks: [],
  }),
  methods: {}
}
</script>
```

'

Comment: Try adding the try-catch statement around your API axios call and handle the error if you get one, or for now just `console.log()` it (you can also log your response, to see if you receive the expected data). You should also check your browser console if it outputs any errors.

Comment: Best practice to use a separate method first for the API call and let it to mounted. posts is not defined in data and still the problem persists, right click on page and click inspect and check in console tab for any error reported

Comment: There are two problems here. The first problem is that you're not showing the error. And the error message typically contains the reason why it happened. The second problem, which is the reason why *"the site crashes"*, is that you're assigning the result to `posts`, but `posts` has not been defined in the context of your component. Add `posts: []` to the object returned by your `data` function. Additionally, you might want to change your `<template/>` so it uses `posts`, when it gets populated. Right now your `v-for` cycles through numbers from `1` to `10`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you tested another `#app` inside your `#inspire` app and forgot to delete it. That might cause problems, as well. I'm guessing your app is mounting into `#inspire`. If it's mounting into `#app` it will ignore a big chunk of your app template.